# Moving the UIImageView Place in UIScrollview to Another UIImageView Placed on Next UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iPhone development. I have added lot of `UIImageview` to the `UIScrollview`. While clicking that `UIImageView` I need to move the particular `UIImageView` to another `UIscrollview` placed on the bottom of the screen as `UIImageView`.

Comment: I think you can write an action that remove ImageView from one ScrollView and add ImageView in other scrollview on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PanGestureRecognizer for this. You need to move the view to the superview of the scrollView while dragging and then after releasing it, you need to place it in the new scrollView correctly.

I wrote a library for exactly this, check out my JDDroppableView Library: https://github.com/jaydee3/JDDroppableView